# Why does the compiler say "Too many actual parameters" when I think I've provided the correct number?

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2005

I've declared the following function:

```
function next(current, next: string): Integer;
begin
    form1.Label1.Caption := next;
    form1.Label2.Caption := current;
    form1.label3.Caption := clipboard.AsText+inttostr(c);
    Result:=1;
end;
```

I try to execute it with this code:

```
if label1.Caption = '' then res := next('current', 'next');
```

I am getting the following error:

> [Error] Unit1.pas(47): E2034 Too many
>   actual parameters

I think all parameters are good, so why am I getting that error?

Comment: It's just a guess but I believe it's the fact that both the parameter name and function name is the same. Try to add for exmple 'A' before the parameter name.

Answer (score 7):

I just tried your code on both Delphi 7 and Delphi 2010. If it works on those two, it should also work on Delphi 2005.

Conclusion: Delphi wants to use a different version of the "next" routine, because of code scope/visibility. Try ctrl+click-ing on "next" in "res := next();" and see where Delphi takes you. Alternatively post more code so we can tell you why Delphi is not choosing your version of the "next" routine. Ideally you should post a whole unit, starting from "unit name" to the final "end."

Answer (score 7):

As specified by Cosmin Prund, the problem is because of the visibility.

`TForm` has a procedure with name `Next` which wont accept any parameters.

Your function uses the same name and as you are calling the function in TForm1 class implementation, compiler is treating the call as `TForm1.Next` and hence it was giving error.

To solve the problem, precede the unit name before the function name i.e., `Unit1.Next()`.

So this should be your code

```
if label1.Caption = '' then res := Unit1.next('current', 'next');
```